# Are network drives visible for Scheduled Tasks?

Tags: windows-xp, scheduled-task, mappeddrive

I have a problem with a scheduled task which uses a mapped network drive. On some days the task does not get executed without any traces in the event log. The task launches an application on a mapped network drive. Most of the time a remote desktop session is active on the computer.

Could it be that when no user is logged in the drive mapping is not available so that the task simply does not find the executable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use mapped drives, the task need to execute in the context of an interactively logged in user. This is why it seems to work only when a user is remoted in. Tasks that need ti access resources over the network should use unc when possible. Drive maps aren't reliable in scheduled tasks.